# How do render swagger.json content in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, swagger, nodejs-express-server

I am trying to create a document portal for my API's with Express and reactJs. Basically, I get the JSON content(swagger.json) from the Express server and I want to pass it to swagger UI on the client to display

In the docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-react), I only see an option to display the URL.

```
render() {
        return <SwaggerUI url="https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json" />;
      }
```

I have the JSON content. Is there another method to pass the JSON content and have it displayed in Swagger UI?

Comment: "In the docs," what docs? Can you be more precise about your actual code? Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-react? If so, then you can use the [`spec`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-react#user-content-spec-proptypesobject) props to pass direct data instead of URL

Comment: Sorry. Yes I am using npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-react and I have the json string not a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-react), you can pass content directly using the `spec` props:

> `spec`: PropTypes.object
>
> An OpenAPI document respresented as a JavaScript object, JSON string, or YAML string for Swagger UI to display.
>
> ⚠️ Don't use this in conjunction with `url` - unpredictable behavior may occur.

Example:

```js
<SwaggerUI spec={jsonData} />
```